# Searching for multiple keywords in a discord message? discord.py bot

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So working on a simple discord bot. I have it all working bar one little thing. I have a few bot replies for different keywords. However there is one bot response that I want to trigger with multiple keywords. ATM I have the same code written out for each keyword. Is there anyway to condense this?

```
if 'SERVER' in message.content.upper():
    await bot.send_message(channel, 'For all Ark Server details type: **nB.arkserver**')
if 'TAMING' in message.content.upper():
    await bot.send_message(channel, 'For all Ark Server details type: **nB.arkserver**')
if 'GATHER' in message.content.upper():
    await bot.send_message(channel, 'For all Ark Server details type: **nB.arkserver**')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and welcome to the community

```
if any([keyword in message.content.upper() for keyword in ('SERVER', 'TAMING', 'GATHER')]):
    await bot.send_message(channel, 'For all Ark Server details type: **nB.arkserver**')
```

Comment: Excellent, worked a treat. I knew there would be a better way to do it. Still learning all the basics. Just threw myself in the deep end :) Many thanks

Comment: Only one way to learn it properly - getting to work ;-) Please use up-vote and mark as solution by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Yeah, every time I get a new piece of code to work I have a flood of ideas that I want to try next. Great feeling. Answer checked and up voted :)